# How to create piles of snow on a mesh?

Tags: modeling, workflow

For example on tree branches like this:

[image]

---

*Image from [Wikimedia commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CathedralofLearningLawinWinter.jpg)*

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is no doubt that the best result can be generated by using Particle or Physics system, which is a bit complicated to talk about in a few words. A quick-and-dirty way is shown as below:

1. Switch Transformation Orientation to **Normal**, try to find and select a single vertex which Z axis towards up (or nearly up). Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to select nearly all possible upward vertices by tweaking a reasonable Threshold value, as shown in Figure 1 and 2.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the selection, then <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to separate it as a new mesh. Now you can freely tweak it with a few modifiers to make a nice pile-looking snow cover, particularly with the Displace modifier. As shown in Figure 3.

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: I remember one Blenderguru tutorial where puts pink sugar over a bagel and he uses the liquids for make it drop over. Doesn't look bad. But this solution is less CPU overkill and accurate than this one.